# Can you turn a realm into a single player world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can you turn a realm into a single player world?

Answer (score 0):

You have to just delete the player folder. It will be converted into single player.

Comment: You should just be able to download it and play it. The player folder shouldn't need to be deleted. Unless this was changed with recent realm updates I have done this several times successfully. I move my world back and forth from realms (because realms doesn't support snapshots and sometimes I want my world in snapshot.)

Comment: but how do you download the realm folder to get it as a single player world?